# Find Exchange User's OfficeLocation in VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

When viewing someone's contact card in Outlook, there is a field for Office which gives their location. How can I find that using VBA? Here's my most functional code:

```
Private Function getLocation(username As String) As String
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olGAL As Outlook.AddressEntries
Dim olAddressEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim olUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olGAL = olNS.AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries
Set olAddressEntry = olGAL.Item(username)
Set olUser = olAddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
Debug.Print olGAL.Count 'count is 646718
Debug.Print olUser.OfficeLocation
Debug.Print olUser.Address
Debug.Print olUser.Name

getLocation = olUser.OfficeLocation

Set olApp = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olGAL = Nothing
Set olAddressEntry = Nothing
Set olUser = Nothing

End Function
```

This works when I search for their actual name (EG, John Smith), but it only returns the first John Smith. How can I use their email address or alias to search?

Note: I added a reference to the `Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library` to take advantage of Intellisense, but I plan on switching to late binding once it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I haven't found a way to query Exchange by email or alias because the `.Item` method (from the line `olGAL.Item(username)`) requires [Either the index number of the object, or a value used to match the default property of an object in the collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220122(v=office.11).aspx). I did find a way to ensure I am getting the correct user however. The default property for the GAL is the user's name, which in my case (but may not be in everyone's case...can't find good documentation to verify this) the DistinguishedName in Active Directory. So if I search AD with the user's SAM account, I can get the user's DN. I can then search Exchange with that DN to ensure I have the correct "John Smith".

Here is my combined code:

```
'I pass the username (EG: johnsmit) and get the DN (eg John Smith - VP of Sales).
' This DN gets passed to the function in my question, and returns the correct location.
Private Function GetFullName(strUsername As String) As String
        Dim objConnection  As Object
        Dim objCommand As Object
        Dim objRecordSet As Object
        Dim strDN As String
        Dim temp As Variant

        Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2

        Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
        objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
        Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

        objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
        objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE

        objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT distinguishedName FROM 'LDAP://dc=mydomain,dc=com' WHERE objectCategory='user' AND sAMAccountName='" & strUsername & "'"
        Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

        objRecordSet.MoveFirst
        Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
            strDN = objRecordSet.Fields("distinguishedName").Value
            temp = Split(strDN, ",")
            GetFullName = Replace(temp(0), "CN=", "")
            objRecordSet.MoveNext
        Loop

        objConnection.Close
        Set objConnection = Nothing
        Set objCommand = Nothing
        Set objRecordSet = Nothing
End Function
```

If anyone has a better, faster, cheaper (one that doesn't hit the AD servers) method, I'd love to hear it.